# RedHat Glibc - multiple packages

Tags: linux, rhel, yum, glibc

Before I jump into the issue, I am using RedHat 6.5 and have no access to the internet to download yum updates due to environment restrictions.  All I have in this case is the CD ROM (RHEL 6.5) to utilize.  After the image is updated, we utilize an internet server to pull updates but prior the server needs to be able to stand on its own.

On the image I need to utilize ldapsearch, so I did a `yum whatprovides */ldapsearch` to figure out which package to install.

I received:

```
openldap-clients-2.4.23-32.el6_4.1.x86_64 : LDAP client utilities
Repo        : cdrom
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/bin/ldapsearch
```

When I go to install this package:

```
[root@test1 yum.repos.d]# yum install openldap-clients-2.4.23-32.el6_4.1.x86_64
Loaded plugins: product-id, security, subscription-manager
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package openldap-clients.x86_64 0:2.4.23-32.el6_4.1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: openldap = 2.4.23-32.el6_4.1 for package: openldap-clients-2.4.23-32.el6_4.1.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package openldap.i686 0:2.4.23-32.el6_4.1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libssl3.so(NSS_3.7.4) for package: openldap-2.4.23-32.el6_4.1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libssl3.so(NSS_3.4) for package: openldap-2.4.23-32.el6_4.1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libssl3.so(NSS_3.2) for package: openldap-2.4.23-32.el6_4.1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libssl3.so for package: openldap-2.4.23-32.el6_4.1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libsmime3.so for package: openldap-2.4.23-32.el6_4.1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libsasl2.so.2 for package: openldap-2.4.23-32.el6_4.1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libresolv.so.2(GLIBC_2.2) for package: openldap-2.4.23-32.el6_4.1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libresolv.so.2 for package: openldap-2.4.23-32.el6_4.1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libplds4.so for package: openldap-2.4.23-32.el6_4.1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libplc4.so for package: openldap-2.4.23-32.el6_4.1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libnssutil3.so for package: openldap-2.4.23-32.el6_4.1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libnss3.so(NSS_3.9.3) for package: openldap-2.4.23-32.el6_4.1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libnss3.so(NSS_3.9.2) for package: openldap-2.4.23-32.el6_4.1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libnss3.so(NSS_3.8) for package: openldap-2.4.23-32.el6_4.1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libnss3.so(NSS_3.6) for package: openldap-2.4.23-32.el6_4.1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libnss3.so(NSS_3.4) for package: openldap-2.4.23-32.el6_4.1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libnss3.so(NSS_3.3) for package: openldap-2.4.23-32.el6_4.1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libnss3.so(NSS_3.2) for package: openldap-2.4.23-32.el6_4.1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libnss3.so(NSS_3.12.9) for package: openldap-2.4.23-32.el6_4.1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libnss3.so(NSS_3.12.5) for package: openldap-2.4.23-32.el6_4.1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libnss3.so(NSS_3.12.1) for package: openldap-2.4.23-32.el6_4.1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libnss3.so(NSS_3.12) for package: openldap-2.4.23-32.el6_4.1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libnss3.so(NSS_3.11.1) for package: openldap-2.4.23-32.el6_4.1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libnss3.so(NSS_3.11) for package: openldap-2.4.23-32.el6_4.1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libnss3.so(NSS_3.10) for package: openldap-2.4.23-32.el6_4.1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libnss3.so for package: openldap-2.4.23-32.el6_4.1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libnspr4.so for package: openldap-2.4.23-32.el6_4.1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.4) for package: openldap-2.4.23-32.el6_4.1.i686
--> Running transaction check
---> Package cyrus-sasl-lib.i686 0:2.1.23-13.el6_3.1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libdb-4.7.so for package: cyrus-sasl-lib-2.1.23-13.el6_3.1.i686
---> Package glibc.i686 0:2.12-1.132.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: glibc-common = 2.12-1.132.el6 for package: glibc-2.12-1.132.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libfreebl3.so(NSSRAWHASH_3.12.3) for package: glibc-2.12-1.132.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libfreebl3.so for package: glibc-2.12-1.132.el6.i686
---> Package nspr.i686 0:4.10.0-1.el6 will be installed
---> Package nss.i686 0:3.15.1-15.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: nss-softokn(x86-32) >= 3.14.3 for package: nss-3.15.1-15.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libz.so.1 for package: nss-3.15.1-15.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libsoftokn3.so for package: nss-3.15.1-15.el6.i686
---> Package nss-util.i686 0:3.15.1-3.el6 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package db4.i686 0:4.7.25-18.el6_4 will be installed
---> Package glibc.i686 0:2.12-1.132.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: glibc-common = 2.12-1.132.el6 for package: glibc-2.12-1.132.el6.i686
---> Package nss-softokn.i686 0:3.14.3-9.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libsqlite3.so.0 for package: nss-softokn-3.14.3-9.el6.i686
---> Package nss-softokn-freebl.i686 0:3.14.3-9.el6 will be installed
---> Package zlib.i686 0:1.2.3-29.el6 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package glibc.i686 0:2.12-1.132.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: glibc-common = 2.12-1.132.el6 for package: glibc-2.12-1.132.el6.i686
---> Package sqlite.i686 0:3.6.20-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libreadline.so.6 for package: sqlite-3.6.20-1.el6.i686
--> Running transaction check
---> Package glibc.i686 0:2.12-1.132.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: glibc-common = 2.12-1.132.el6 for package: glibc-2.12-1.132.el6.i686
---> Package readline.i686 0:6.0-4.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libtinfo.so.5 for package: readline-6.0-4.el6.i686
--> Running transaction check
---> Package glibc.i686 0:2.12-1.132.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: glibc-common = 2.12-1.132.el6 for package: glibc-2.12-1.132.el6.i686
---> Package ncurses-libs.i686 0:5.7-3.20090208.el6 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: glibc-2.12-1.132.el6.i686 (cdrom)
           Requires: glibc-common = 2.12-1.132.el6
           Installed: glibc-common-2.12-1.132.el6_5.2.x86_64 (@updates)
               glibc-common = 2.12-1.132.el6_5.2
           Available: glibc-common-2.12-1.132.el6.x86_64 (cdrom)
               glibc-common = 2.12-1.132.el6
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

It would seem that I do not have the right package for my version installed already:

```
[root@test1 yum.repos.d]# rpm -qa | grep glibc
glibc-common-2.12-1.132.el6_5.2.x86_64
glibc-2.12-1.132.el6_5.2.x86_64
```

Obviously if I try and remove glibc and reinstall from the CD-ROM which would provide a newer version I receive a whole lot of errors since glibc cannot exactly be removed...

```
[root@test1 yum.repos.d]# yum install glibc*
Loaded plugins: product-id, security, subscription-manager
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
Setting up Install Process
Package matching glibc-2.12-1.132.el6.x86_64 already installed. Checking for update.
Package matching glibc-common-2.12-1.132.el6.x86_64 already installed. Checking for update.
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package glibc-devel.x86_64 0:2.12-1.132.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: glibc = 2.12-1.132.el6 for package: glibc-devel-2.12-1.132.el6.x86_64
---> Package glibc-headers.x86_64 0:2.12-1.132.el6 will be installed
---> Package glibc-utils.x86_64 0:2.12-1.132.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libgd.so.2()(64bit) for package: glibc-utils-2.12-1.132.el6.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package gd.x86_64 0:2.0.35-11.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libXpm.so.4()(64bit) for package: gd-2.0.35-11.el6.x86_64
---> Package glibc.i686 0:2.12-1.132.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: glibc-common = 2.12-1.132.el6 for package: glibc-2.12-1.132.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libfreebl3.so(NSSRAWHASH_3.12.3) for package: glibc-2.12-1.132.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libfreebl3.so for package: glibc-2.12-1.132.el6.i686
--> Running transaction check
---> Package glibc.i686 0:2.12-1.132.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: glibc-common = 2.12-1.132.el6 for package: glibc-2.12-1.132.el6.i686
---> Package libXpm.x86_64 0:3.5.10-2.el6 will be installed
---> Package nss-softokn-freebl.i686 0:3.14.3-9.el6 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: glibc-2.12-1.132.el6.i686 (cdrom)
           Requires: glibc-common = 2.12-1.132.el6
           Installed: glibc-common-2.12-1.132.el6_5.2.x86_64 (@updates)
               glibc-common = 2.12-1.132.el6_5.2
           Available: glibc-common-2.12-1.132.el6.x86_64 (cdrom)
               glibc-common = 2.12-1.132.el6
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Are you mismatching your architecture?

Uname -i  vs  filenames on the CD

I'm seeing a LOT of i686 there, where I may want to see x86_64; or the other way around. When I see this, and the dependency barf, it's always been an arch mismatch.

Good hunting.